# Android Deep link- Supported web addresses

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I've implemented an Android deep link with a support web address but,

It's **not enabled by default** in the app and I don't know the reason, I should go to the app setting and enable it manually to start working as shown here:

[image: my app deeplink].

My question is how to enable it by default when installing the app?

My Manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="winwinapp.net" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: if you want to use deeplink in google ads, maybe make your project support DDL                     <!-- Value to be added to enable deferred deep links -->
     <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_deferred_deep_link_enabled" android:value="true"/>      read more about it in this link                                             
           https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/12373942?hl=en&sjid=8398826018943482010-AP#zippy=%2Csteps-to-activate-ddl-in-the-gaf-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only be enabled by default if the domain is configured properly. Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks.

Summary:

1. Upload `https://winwinapp.net/.well-known/assetlinks.json` to your server. (Example format in the documentation)
2. Add scheme to your app
3. Make sure you set `android:autoVerify="true"` to your link.

This is done to prevent apps from hijacking deeplinks. For example, to prevent a malicious developer from registering `facebook.com` to go to their app instead of the official one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your app is in the **release variant-version**. Additionally, make sure that the **assetlinks.json** file is sent to the correct address.

```
android:autoVerify="true"
```

will automatically provide selection.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure add `SHA1` to firebase for development. Other thing, make sure add `SHA1` from play console to Firebase for production.